# xhr GET with some header is not working?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I have a javascript function which takes two values as parameter which I'm sending from html(username and token value(say:34378463782 ). I'm trying to make a rest call using GET method and have to send token as a requestheader with the call. All I need to know, is there anything wrong with code?

Here is the code:

```
               function getUser(user,token)
               {
                var xmlhttp;
                 var text,x,i;
                 var url="http://abc.xyz.com:8890/uauth/" +user;


           alert("url :"+url);



         if (window.XMLHttpRequest)

              {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();

                   if (xmlhttp==null)
                      {

                      alert ("Browser does not support HTTP Request");
                      return;

                      }
              }

         else

              {// code for IE6, IE5

                 xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");

              }

         xmlhttp.open("GET",url, true);
         alert("Outside the Main Code");
         xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
                 {
                       alert("Above the Main Code if block");
                       if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
                          {
                            alert("Inside the Main Code");

                            xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML;
                            text="";
                            x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("response");

                                for (i=0;i<x.length;i++)
                                    {
                                     text=text + x[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue + "<br />";
                                    }

                            document.getElementById("myNewDiv").innerHTML=text;

                           }

                  };
         xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("xyz-Authorization: ", token);
         xmlhttp.send(null);


    }
```

Pls no suggestions for jquery use.

Comments welcome.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use [jquery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) to xhr-ing. It is more clear.